# What type to use for integers larger than 2^32?

Tags: c#

I have an integer variable, that can get a value larger than 4294967295.
What type should I use for it?

Comment: You go to a table with C# (CLR) types and pick one with more than 32 bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) (Int64):

> The Int64 value type represents integers with values ranging from negative 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through positive 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

An alternative is [`ulong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.aspx) (UInt64):

> The UInt64 value type represents unsigned integers with values ranging from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

If that's not enough look at [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx):

> Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the int64 type in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The type `long` is 64 bits long and can contain values in the range of

```
long:  -2^63 ... 2^63 - 1    (~ -9.22 * 10^18 ... 9.22 * 10^18)
```

compared to `int` which is 32 bits long and has a range of

```
int:  -2^31 ... 2^31 - 1    (~ -2.15 * 10^9 ... 2.15 * 10^9)
```

the unsigned variants have

```
ulong:  0 ... 2^64 - 1    (~ 0 ... 1.84 * 10^19)
uint:   0 ... 2^32 - 1    (~ 0 ... 4.29 * 10^9)
```

Note that all these types can be converted to `decimal` without loss of precision.

```
decimal:  ~ -7.92 * 10^28 ... 7.92 * 10^28
```

However, `decimal` is not an integer type.